# What can we say about two sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $s_n$ and $t_n$ be two strictly positive sequences. Let $t_n$ be increasing and $s_nt_n$ converges to $0$. Is it true that $s_n$ should converge to $0$? If yes, then how do I go about proving it. Are there any other conclusions we can draw and prove about $s_n$ and $t_n$?

Comment: What can you conclude about the sequence $1/t_n\;$? Maybe useful that $s_n = (1/t_n)(s_n t_n)$

Comment: @311411 that it is decreasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$t_n>0$ is increasing, so it is bounded below, $t_n\ge t_1>0$, so we have $$0< \frac{1}{t_n}\le \frac{1}{t_1}$$

$$0<s_n=s_nt_n\cdot \frac{1}{t_n}\le s_nt_n\cdot \frac{1}{t_1}$$

$$0\le\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n\le \frac{1}{t_1}\lim_{n\to\infty} s_nt_n=0$$

So by squeeze theorem, $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n=0$